# PHP: Get ZIP file contents from memory, without ever saving it to a disk

Tags: php, memory, zip, archive

I'm working on a auto-import system for an API that provides data in a ZIP archive. I'm looking for a way to download this archive from the internet and reading it's contents without ever having to save it to a disk.

I've already tried multiple things. The standard ZipArchive class can't read data from memory so that's out. The `ZipFile` class from phpMyAdmin/CodeIgniter can only archive, not unarchive. I finally settled on using `file_get_contents` with `zip://` but for that I have to save the file first and that causes a mess with permissions.

Using third party libraries is no problem. It's important that the solution can open a file downloaded from the internet and saved in memory (so probably in `string` form or something.).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: vague guess: have you tried `$zip->open('http://...../foo.zip')`?

Comment: @MarcB Do you mean with $zip being an instance of `ZipFile`?

Comment: @MarcB That might work but then you can only do `extractTo` which saves it...

Comment: Can you use curl? OK that doesn't help your zip problem; but you could redirect the output to `unzip` by calling a system command; that's a little gross, but might work.

Comment: @jhaagsma I think I'm just going to save it... Deadlines and all. Still pretty ridiculous that this is not possible in PHP. Or at least not elegantly. Might write an API wrapper on my own server some day in Ruby or something.